# How do you build an iPhone App with MobiOne?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, windows, mobione

I'm using MobiOne to build an App (I don't have a Mac or know Obj-C), but I'm wondering how to compile the App into Obj-C. Has anyone tried this? I have my design done and tested in the emulator, but do not see how to build the code.

Comment: http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/docs/highlights/1.4.0EA1/

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that MobiOne is not designed to be uploaded to Apple's app store. You can use Phone Gap to help get your app into a native environment since MobiOne uses web technologies. Phone Gap should allow you to publish to the app store, but the app is still subject to Apple's quality control system.

EDIT: You will still need a mac to publish the app. Or you can just use the app as a website on your device(s).

Comment: MobiOne appears to have PhoneGap built-in. http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/docs/highlights/1.4.0EA1/

Comment: There you go. use PhoneGap that is included to compile your app. You will still need a mac to publish though. and I doubt MobiOne will allow to compile if your are using the trial version.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the app with the Mobione built-in compiler. Go to the "Project" menu and click "Build iOS app" and your app will be compiled. You cannot compile with Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it into an iOS native app using Mobione on Windows. Upload it to the App Store using Apple's Application Uploader on a Mac. Easy.

Answer (score -2):

According to Apple, you are not supposed to make iPhone apps without a mac. Also learning objective c MIGHT just be a good first start before making an app.

The first comment in your question provides a link, and one of the first paragraphs in that link states this:

"**The traditional approach to iOS application development requires developers to create their apps using Apple’s Objective-C programming tools and Macintosh(tm) hardware**. MobiOne runs on your Windows OS (Win7 to XP) hardware and offers developers an alternative cross-platform programming model based on HTML5 open web standards and virtual device services, e.g., contacts, camera, audio... "

Of course this allows you to do it, but that doesn't mean that the appstore will accept your app if you try and submit it through MobiOne. I'm not too sure on the subject, but I would do some research and figure out if apple allows you to do this.

Comment: Apple allows non-Objective-C apps created with things like Titanium (I've successfully submitted one of those) or PhoneGap. MobiOne looks like it uses PhoneGap.